# nox: Install different versions of dependency using poetry according to Python version

Tags: python, python-poetry, nox

I am using `nox` in order to test my code against different Python versions. I have a dependent package that is stored on my local hard drive. I add this package via `poetry` with the following command:

```
poetry add ./path/to/package/local_package_py310.whl
```

My `pyproject.toml` file then contains the following line in the `[tool.poetry.dependencies]` section:

```
local_package = {path = "./path/to/package/local_package_py310.whl"}
```

This works fine for the regular Python version that I use (py 3.10). However, when using `nox` to test my package under Python 3.9, I need to install a different version of this package, namely `./path/to/package/local_package_py39.whl`.

My `noxfile.py` looks like this and the tests for 3.10 do pass.

```
@nox.session(python=["3.10", "3.9"])
def tests(session) -> None:
    """Run the test suite."""
    session.run("poetry", "install",  external=True)
    session.run("pytest")
```

However, the test are failing for 3.9 due to the fact that in this case my `pyproject.toml` is incorrect. It should read:

```
local_package = {path = "./path/to/package/local_package_py39.whl"}
```

Is it possible to modify the `pyproject.toml` according to the Python version that `nox` is using`?

Comment: One of the strengths of `nox` is that you can use normal Python code, so you could specify this in the function call itself.  However, Poetry has already solved for your specific use case:  https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#python-restricted-dependencies